# CMS icons pointing to wrong site

Tags: control-panel

I've got a site that is live that is still referencing URLs from the development site.  Nothing major, but some icons in the CMS are missing, and when I try to pull them up, they are pointing to an old URL (development site).  I've searched the config files, as well as the database, but the path doesn't come up.

Not a huge deal, but it bugs me every time I log in.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the Control Panel? If look go to Settings and then URL and Path Settings, what are the paths set to? Your might also check for any config overrides.

Comment: Sorry - yeah, in the control panel.  I've searched all of the files for the site, as well as the database.  The only place I've found that URL referenced was in the conf.env.php file (using Focus Lab's Master Config).  I also have Deploy Helper installed, and it doesn't find anything referencing that URL.  Very strange!

Comment: that is strange... did you try from another machine? one outside your local network?